# Telegram API и Telegram Bot API Как переслать сообщение с чужого канала в свой?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, tlsharp

Задача получить сообщение из чужого канала и переслать его в свой.
Bot API не позволяет парсить чужие каналы, поэтому для получения сообщения из канала я использую **TLSharp**.

Получаю последнее сообщение в канале:

```
public async Task<TLMessage> GetLastMessage(TLChannel channelFrom)
{
    TLChannelMessages resp = (TLChannelMessages)await _client.GetHistoryAsync(new TLInputPeerChannel()
    {
        ChannelId = channelFrom.Id,
        AccessHash = channelFrom.AccessHash ?? 0,
    }, limit: 1000);

    TLMessage lastMessage = (TLMessage)resp.Messages?.Where(x => x is TLMessage).First();
    return lastMessage;
}
```

Метод возвращает переменную типа `TLMessage`, в это и есть сообщение.
Провозился весь день, как либо распарсить его не смог.

Нужно это сообщение отравить в свой канал с помощью Bot API.

Обычные сообщения отправляю вот так:

Текстовое сообщение:

```
TelegramBotClient client = new TelegramBotClient(ApiKey);
await client.SendTextMessageAsync(MyChatId, "Hello World");
```

Сообщение с медиа:

```
var photos = post.Photo.Select(x => new InputMediaPhoto(x)).ToList();
              
botClient = new TelegramBotClient(TelegramToken);
Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
    chatId: Channel,
    inputMedia: photos
);
```

Как можно методу `SendMediaGroupAsync` передать `TLMessage`?

Спасибо

Comment: [Оно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43136155/12888024)?

Comment: @aepot, мне нужно сообщение полученное с помощью TLSharp отправить в канала через Bot API

Comment: Значит скорее всего нужно его получить, разобрать на составляющие, скачать файлы и отправить как новое сообщение.

Comment: @aepot, вот с этим и проблема

Comment: Вы спрашиваете _Как можно методу SendMediaGroupAsync передать TLMessage?_ Ответ - напрямую никак.